# Mongoose store all query results in a sortable container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this Mongoose schema:

```
UserSchema = new db.Schema({
        objA                : [objA.Schema],
        objB                : [objB.Schema],
        objC                : [objC.Schema],
        objD                : [objD.Schema],
        friends             : [db.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
```

I used this query to get hold of the `_id`s inside `objA, objB, objC and objD` based on the contents of the `friends` object:

```
user.Model
        .find({
            _id : {
                $in : friends
            }
        })
        .select('-_id objA._id objB._id objC._id objD._id') //get the _ids
        .exec(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
```

the `results` show:

```
[ { objD: [ { _id: 52395c8cee93d72344000009 } ],
    objC: [],
    objA: 
     [ { _id: 52395a408078b3f42200000d },
       { _id: 52395cc1ee93d7234400000c } ],
    objB: [ { _id: 52395d06ee93d7234400000f } ] },

  { objD: [],
    objC: [],
    objA: [ { _id: 52395a248078b3f422000009 } ],
    objB: [] } ]
```

Everything works fine as expected. But my goal is to put all the _ids of objA,B,C and D inside  a container (maybe an array, object... I don't know) wherein I can sort them by timestamp easily and populate the UI with them. I think there is a very convenient approach for this. Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB provides a built-in sort() option on its queries, and you can easily use this feature through Mongoose.  When using Mongoose, you can also iterate over the returned objects multiple times (unlike a cursor, which is exhausted after iteration).  So, you can simply have the query return your documents in timestamp-sorted order by including a "sort" option in your query, like this:

```
var query = myModel.find({}, null, { sort : { timestamp : 1 }});
```

Comment: is there a way for me to store them all inside an array wherein they are already sorted by timestamp and all I need is to make a loop on it? TIA